# how do i set the hibernate session timeout in jboss-seam?

Tags: hibernate, jboss, seam

HOW DO I SET THE HIBERNATE SESSION TIMEOUT IN JBOSS-SEAM?

I Have an upload interface with a for in server side that read line by line from a file. Each line is inserted in database and after import around 4.000 lines the connection is lost and the following erros is returned:

11:04:00,750 WARN  [arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction_58] - Abort of action id -3f57feaf:d6b:4f0adc25:946 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
11:04:00,750 WARN  [arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.CheckedAction_2] - CheckedAction::check - atomic action -3f57feaf:d6b:4f0adc25:946 aborting with 1 threads active!
11:04:02,766 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
11:04:02,766 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -3f57feaf:d6b:4f0adc25:946 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -3f57feaf:d6b:4f0adc25:946 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >)
11:04:03,562 ERROR [ImportarArquivoTransacaoBusiness] Erro ao importar a linha 4007 do arquivo ITA_COM_49925225000148_20111226_00193.txt para o DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "hibernate session timeout" doesn't exist.

What you are experiencing is actually a transaction timeout.
In JBoss you set this in the `conf/jboss-service.xml` configuration file. See [here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/TransactionTimeout) for details.